# Twitter の OAuth のバージョンについて

Tags: twitter, oauth

下記のように書いてあるのですが、Twitter が OAuth2 に対応したのはいつからですか？
・[Twitter uses OAuth 1.0a and OAuth2 to provide authorized access to the API.](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/oauth)

---

ネットに色々な情報が掲載されているのですが、
・「Request Token」使用している場合は「OAuth 1」、「refresh_token」使用している場合は「OAuth 2」と考えてよいですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth1.0については知らないので前者についてだけですが:

> Twitter が OAuth2 に対応したのはいつからですか？

2013年3月11日からのようです。

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19040860/4506703

  - [参照されているblogエントリの現在のリンク](https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/a/2013/application-only-authentication.html)